# How do I skip a txt file when iterating over a directory?

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

Alright, so I'm trying to write a simple shell script to check for updates or just update all packages, including homebrew itself. I am trying to echo the executable filenames into a txt file, and source the txt file at the end. The problem is that in my script, no matter what I do, it always includes the name of the text file in the text file it creates. How do I either skip over the text file, or remove the entire line containing `pkg.txt`? Keep in mind that it won't be as simple as just removing the last line, because the packages are listed alphabetically and if I ever install any package starting with a letter that's greater than p, it will delete that line instead.

Here's my code so far.

```
for FILE in $HOME/.brew/bin/* ; do
  TRIM=$(basename $FILE)
  if [ "$FILE" != "*.txt" ] ; then
    echo "brew upgrade \c" >>  pkg.txt ; echo $TRIM >> pkg.txt
  fi
done
```

Not sure if it matters, but I'm currently running zsh in iTerm2.

Comment: Is your *script* going to be run with bash or zsh? (Much of the syntax is incorrect for bash, in ways that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch). That is, does the first start line start with `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`, or something else? (`#!/bin/sh` means only POSIX sh baseline is guaranteed).

Comment: ...if the interpreter itself isn't bash, then the `bash` tag shouldn't be used in the StackOverflow question.

Comment: BTW, it'd be more efficient to put the `>> pkg.txt` on the `done`, thus opening the output file only once for the whole loop, rather than re-opening the file every time you want to write a single line to it and closing it after you've written that one line.

Comment: BTW, as a second aside, all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html; using lower-case names for your own variables prevents you from overwriting system-meaningful ones by mistake. (If I had a dollar for every time I saw someone write `for PATH in */; do`, I could at least buy a cup of coffee).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Sorry, changed it from bash to zsh. I have #!/bin/zsh at the top because that's what it says when i use `where zsh` -- I want it to be run by zsh, but it doesn't seem to like certain zsh commands. It also complains if I try to source the .zshrc from a shell script with an error that usually hints that you are sourcing the file with a shell other than zsh.

Comment: Sourcing dotfiles from scripts is... generally considered a bad idea regardless. A script should work reliably on different accounts and machines -- when you start adopting customizations that were created for interactive use, you're compromising that. Anyhow, any important environment variables needed when running under a given account should be exported by the *login* shell, and thus inherited through the environment by its children. (This is why there are traditionally separate `.profile` and `.rc` files).

Comment: I understand, but this is a special circumstance in my opinion. I am doing this for the computers at school. The way I have things setup in the install script, it will work for any person's account on the schools network. Since it wouldn't let me source, I just used `exec /bin/zsh` at the very end and that took care of sourcing. Probably pretty sloppy, but hey, I'm new.

Comment: You could do that in 1 line `find "$HOME/.brew/bin" \( -type f -a ! -name \*.txt \) -exec bash -c "printf 'brew upgrade %s\n' \$(basename '{}')" \; > pkg.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` to match a pattern.

```
for FILE in "$HOME"/.brew/bin/* ; do
  TRIM=$(basename "$FILE")
  case "$FILE" in
    *.txt) ;;
    *) echo "brew upgrade '$TRIM'" >> pkg.txt ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Carrying through the quoting bugs? Tsk. (`"$HOME"/.brew/bin/*`, and `basename "$FILE"`, at minimum).

Comment: (granted, it's a bit unclear whether the OP is mentioning zsh in the context of being their interactive shell or the shell actually interpreting the script, but I'm *assuming* that the `bash` tag means it's only the former).

Comment: Thanks. Although In practice I suspect there are 0 $HOME directories with whitespace. Home directories are practically always named after the user, and I don't think spaces are allowed in usernames.

Comment: I've seen *usernames* with whitespace on Cygwin.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - It's meant to be both, the bash tag was a mistake. Barmar Barmar - Thanks for the answer, I'm not ignoring it, I'm just trying to see if I can get that other guy's solution working first because it's a bit simpler and I'm new to shell scripting

Comment: This is the working answer for me. I couldn't seem to get that other guy's solution to work for me. Thank you @Barmar .

Answer (score 2):

It fails because `[ "$FILE" != "*.txt" ]` is a literal string comparison.

Zsh supports `[[ "$FILE" != *.txt ]]` to match against a pattern (also supported by bash and ksh. For `dash` and `sh`, use @Barmar's suggestion).

Here it is in your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
for FILE in $HOME/.brew/bin/* ; do
  TRIM=$(basename $FILE)
  if [[ "$FILE" != *.txt ]] ; then
    echo "brew upgrade \c" >>  pkg.txt ; echo $TRIM >> pkg.txt
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just out of curiousity, how do I use zsh only command in a shell script and have it be executed by zsh? I've had problems in the past where certain commands weren't working because (I would assume) it was being executed as a bash command. I've tried `where zsh` and put #!`where zsh output` at the top of my file but it didn't help. Also tried `exec /bin/zsh` but that just ended the script.

Comment: *nod* -- and with zsh as the explicit interpreter, then all the missing quotes are no longer bug-inducing in the event of a home directory or `bin` files with spaces or glob characters in their names.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning, use `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` if you want to ensure that your script is interpreted with `zsh` but don't know where the zsh binary will be.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning And also make sure never to run a script with `sh somefile`, it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Doesn't `where zsh` tell you where the binary is? Either way, I believe I've tried that in the past, but I will try it again.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning, `where` isn't a standardized command. The portable alternative is `command -v`. Anyhow, re: "didn't help" -- if it didn't help, the easy presumption is that your script was run in a way that didn't honor the shebang (like `sh yourscript` instead of `./yourscript`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just tried it again with `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` and it still doesn't work. I already have been running it with sh -- does it matter whether or not I use the .sh file extension? Because I'm not.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning, re: "running it with sh", that's what we're (many times over now!) telling you **not** to do. Stop running it with sh. Running it with `sh` forces the shebang line to be ignored. You do not want the shebang line to be ignored if you want your interpreter choice to be honored.